# Select statement for over ride values from other table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select, inner-join

I have a few tables that look like this:

**table 1**

```
Registration#   Name    Phone          Extension
1               John    111-111-2233   987
2               Peter   332-444-2232   345
3               John    323-987-8372   234
4               tom     841-654-9875   254
```

**table2**

```
Registration#   PersonalPhone   Extension   Company 
2               125-541-1241    123         ABC
3               125-965-8457    852         BVC
```

Result of the query should be

If `Where Condition Company=ABC`

```
Registration#   Name    Phone   Extension      Company 
1               John    111-111-2233    987 
2               Peter   125-541-1241    123    ABC
3               John    323-987-8372    234 
4               tom     841-654-9875    254
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use an `INNER JOIN` for this, you want to use a `LEFT JOIN` and put your filter for the `Company` in your join condition.  Since you also want to replace the `Phone` and `Extension` from `Table2` if it exists, you'll want to use [`COALESCE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm#SQLRF00617) or something similar to override those values from `Table1` if they are returned:

```
select 
  t1."Registration#",
  t1.Name,
  coalesce(t2.PersonalPhone, t1.Phone) as Phone,
  coalesce(t2.Extension, t1.Extension) as Extension, 
  t2.Company
from Table1 t1
left join Table2 t2
  on t1."Registration#" = t2."Registration#"
  and t2.Company = 'ABC'
order by t1."Registration#";
```

Here is a [demo](http://rextester.com/HEGW61679).

Comment: Up voting this because you also caught the requirement to use coalesce to change out the extension numbers, I glossed over that part

Answer (score 1):

Don't make your condition part of the WHERE clause, make it a condition of the LEFT join between table1 and table2 instead

```
SELECT * FROM
  table1 a
  LEFT JOIN
  table2 b
  ON
    a."registration#" = b."registration#" AND
    b.company = 'ABC' --parameterise this I.e. @companyName
```

Don't forget to parameterise your queries

Don't use # in column names - makes them a pain in the backside to use in other systems (particularly) because they need escaping, and also escaping columns in oracle means you have to get the case Bob on. Anything that makes a query more fragile should be avoided

In some versions of oracle, it is sensitive to which way round you write the conditions (hopefully this was only a bug in only ancient versions)

If you struggle with results being weird or unexpected try:

```
LEFT JOIN table2 ....
ON 'ABC' = table2.companyname
```

Comment: Note: see ollies answer for a more complete example using coalesce to replace the extension number for matching rows. I missed that part of your requirement